# Form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to create form validation with jquerys ajax. The problem I am facing is there is a div called error where the error is displayed. I am using the keyup functions and doing validation as the user types. The parts I need help with is could this check be applied to all the input fields or will I have to create individual checks for each of the fields. The second question is I would like when the first field is OK the error div disappears. For this I used the slide function but what I am wondering if the first field is not ok and the person goes to the second field, how can I show error depending on which field is the user focusing on. Lastly there is a flaw which I have not really thought of how can I fix this. Once the field is OK the div has disappears but if the person changes something where the field was OK ,I would like the div to come back.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var error = $('#error');    
    $('#firstname').keyup(function () {
        var t = this;    
        if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
            if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
            error.removeClass('error').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" height="16" width="16" /> checking availability...');
            this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'reg_valid.php',
                    data: 'firstname=' + t.value,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        error.html(data);
                        if (data=="Ok") {
                            $('#error').slideUp();  
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 200);
            this.lastValue = this.value;
        }
    });
});

<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' />
<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' />
```

Finally if I should go with another type of form validation please do tell thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [jQuery Validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)?  I suspect it will do what you are looking for

i'v e used [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and it works really well.